# Show results without creating new table using join and substring

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have this code here, that selects 13 characters from the wanted column:

```
`select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes
```

I need to select first 13 characters and join it with another table. But I dont want to create a new table and then join. What is the way just to show results in Workbench?

I have tried the following:

```
`select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes join bridgeb on 
`outerbarcodes.test = bridgeb.barcode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes join bridgeb on 
outerbarcodes.test = bridgeb.barcode
```

it's not possible the use select aliases in `ON`, `WHERE` clauses, a select alias can only be used in `HAVING` clause

You need to do

```
select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes join bridgeb on 
substring(barcode,1,13) = bridgeb.barcodes
```

Or

```
select barcode, test from (
  select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes
) as outerbarcodes join bridgeb on 
outerbarcodes.test = bridgeb.barcodes
```

Comment: Amazing! Im gonna look into the two codes now see whats going on

Comment: the 1st one says error code: 1052 but the 2nd works amazing

Comment: yes the ambiguous error best is to **always** use fully quantified names or aliases in SQL. @Eduards meaning writting `select table.barcode, substring(table.barcode,1,13) ...`

Comment: Understood, thanks for your help. Where did you learn Sql out of curiosit

Comment: How would I return values that dont exist? i have tried this `select * from where not exists (select barcode, substring(barcode,1,13) as test from outerbarcodes) as outerbarcodes join bridgeb on 
outerbarcodes.test = bridgeb.barcode;`

Comment: @Eduards by reading the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) and trying.. The return missing values thing is "out of scope" of this question you should ask a new question, with example data, expected results and everything..

Comment: But i assume you meant i want to know if one value existis in one table and not in the other one..Take a look into `NOT IN()` or `... LEFT JOIN .. WHERE column IS NULL` syntaxes @Eduards